# Simple Form Association in HTML Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have the following situation. I have two table Student and Course linked via HABTM association.

On Student form, I want to have a list of Courses, however I need more information displayed than a simple checkbox and a label next to it. Essentially, I want to have an HTML table with information from my Course model with a checkbox for the association in the first column of the table.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried nested_form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially this did it:

I iterated through my @courses collection and created each checkbox manually like this:

`check_box_tag "student[course_ids][]", course.id`

In my controller params I added this:

`params.require[:student].permit(... ,course_ids: [])`

My Student model needed this:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses`

Pretty simple if you know what you're doing :-)